# How to make Down arrow icon by pure css to use it as a background?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a down arrow like this using pure css to use it as a background?

Actual size image

[image]

Enlarged images

[image]

I know it's possible to use an image and we can make this arrow with the [border tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) too

```
#triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
}
```

But this we can't use as a background. Is there a way to make the arrow to use as a css background.

Comment: Why must this be done in pure CSS? Why not an image?

Comment: Becuase of color of arrow will change multiple times on various interactions. so instead of using multiple images of arrow I was just curious to know it's possible to make in css and to just change the color of arrow using css.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: That problem has already been solved using sprites.

Comment: @BoltClock - I know that it's possible with an image and I will use that but I was just curious to know if it's possible with css. if it's not then will use css sprite

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a CSS pattern on an element and then use that pattern as a CSS background of another element. You can cheat by using pseudo-elements or adding other child elements in your HTML, but a pure CSS background image isn't possible.

You'll have to make an image and use that as a background image instead.

Comment: I think there is a possibility that it isn't meant to repeat as that wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after but you can make it appear as a background like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/8vHQF/1/

```
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    z-index: 0;
}

.content{  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Personally I'd use a sprite though.

Comment: Don't know why, but after I fiddled with your example, the borders smoothed: http://jsfiddle.net/nitech/W3hNx/

Comment: Odd. This still isn't going to look as good as an image but it's a nice experiment.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't know this was possible with css.